# Scatter plot to show the majorities and include extreme numbers

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Simple data as below and I want to put them in a scatter plot.

It goes well if there's not outliers (i.e. extremely big numbers).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()

dates = ["2021-01-01",
"2021-01-01", "2021-01-06",
"2021-01-08", "2021-01-12",
"2021-02-01", "2021-02-11",
"2021-02-12", "2021-02-15",
"2021-02-16", "2021-03-11",
"2021-03-21", "2021-03-22",
"2021-03-23", "2021-03-24",
"2021-04-02", "2021-04-12",
"2021-04-22", "2021-04-26",
"2021-04-30"]

numbers= [6400,
5100,5000,
4000,3686,
9000,8050,
8000,6050,
6000,9000,
8500,7800,
7000,6000,
10000,9600,
8000,7883,
6686]

dates = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in dates]

plt.scatter(dates, numbers, s =100, c = 'red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

But when there are one or more extreme numbers, for example the last number 6686 became 66860. The new plot shows most the scatters insignificant (because of the the new y-axis).

[image]

What's the good solution to have a scatter plot as before (keeping the y-axis as it was), and still visualizing the extreme numbers?

The purpose of the chart is show and focus the distribution of the scatters under 10000, and also note there are extreme numbers.

Comment: You could use a log scale. The real question is what information do you want to convey in this graph?

Comment: @mozway, thank you for your comment. the readers of the chart doesn't understand the log scale concept, so preferably keep the y-axis as usual.

Comment: @mozway, the purpose of the chart is show and focus the distribution of the scatters (of numbers) under 10000, and also note there are extreme numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a log scale, you can break the plot in two (or more) and plot the values below/above a threshold:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': numbers}, index=dates)
thresh = 12000

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True,
                             gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': (1,3)},
                             figsize=(10,4)
                            )

lows  = df.mask(df['num'].ge(thresh))
highs = df.mask(df['num'].lt(thresh))

ax2.scatter(df.index, lows)
ax1.scatter(df.index, highs)
```

output:

[image]